# Return only the 'msg:' from Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a simple playbook to query a package version

```
---
- name: version find
  hosts: all
  become: yes


    tasks:
          - name: query
            shell: *shell command*
            register: info
            no_log: true

           - debug:
                  msg: " {{inventory_hostname}} blah {{info.stdout}}blah"
```

I get an output with a lot of junk that makes parsing/using the output difficult without edits:

```
   ok: [hostname] => {
    "msg": " *hostname* blah *info* blah"
   }
```

I am trying find a solution to only return the msg without the "ok:", and JSON-esque junk that comes with it.

I have tried setting `no_log:True` in the YAML file and the ansible.cfg files with no luck.

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to understand what [playbook callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/plugins/callback.html) do, and then pick your favorite or author one that behaves as you wish. `ansible-doc -t callback --list` will show you the ones you currently have installed

Comment: Based solely upon that one example, you may also be happier with the ad-hoc version: `ansible -i ./whatever -m shell -a "my-thing --version" all` since it is less chatty by nature

Answer (score 6):

Use the callback [*community.general.diy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-diy-callback) (*do it yourself*). See

```
shell> ansible-doc -t callback community.general.diy
```

For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - command: uname -o
      register: info

    - debug:
        msg: ""
      vars:
        ansible_callback_diy_runner_on_ok_msg: |
          msg: {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ info.stdout }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=community.general.diy ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
msg: localhost GNU/Linux

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```